# Java exceptions and program flow: how to know if the program will stop or continue after an exception is thrown?

Tags: java, exception

Check this code:

```
public class Tests {

    public static Boolean test() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Boolean b = test();
        System.out.println("boolean = " + b);
    }
}
```

Why the System.out.println() line is not executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't executed because uncaught exceptions terminate the current thread(main thread in your case).

test() throws a RuntimeException. Surrounding test() with a try-catch would catch the exception and allow your program to continue.

```
try {
    test();
} catch(RuntimeException e) {
    System.out.println("test() failed");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions "bubble up" to the "highest" level exception handler.

In this case, it's the JVM itself with the exception handler, since you define none.

The JVM will halt program execution since it doesn't know what else to do with the uncaught exception.

Comment: Actually, it's just the [default uncaught exception handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()). It's just regular Java code.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Right, which the JVM provides.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `test()` method which throws exception. The program will stop executing as soon as exception is thrown and not handled. You need to handle exception by putting it in `try-catch` block

```
public static Boolean test() {
         try{
             throw new RuntimeException(); 
         }catch(RuntimeException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
            return true;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Boolean b = test();
            System.out.println("boolean = " + b);
        }
}
```

or you can declare the method to throw exception and handle it in the main method

```
public static Boolean test() throws RuntimeException {
             throw new RuntimeException(); 
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Boolean b = false;
            try{
                b = test();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("boolean = " + b);

        }
```

- If an exception is thrown in try block, all the statements below it won't be executed and then catch block is executed.
- If there is no catch block, then finally block is executed.
- Finally block will be executed all the times if JVM does not shut down.